# Connect mongodb across 2 ubuntu 14 servers

Tags: networking, server, maas, mongodb

I have a node app install in `10.10.xx.xx1` and a mongod server running in `10.10.xx.xx2`. Both servers are running on a same network.

I am trying to connect the node app to the mongo server from the other server using the link `mongod://10.10.xx.xx2` but I got a connection error.

**mongod service is running**

[image]

**mongo connection error**

[image]

Did I missed something?

Comment: Have you updated the [`bindIp` setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) in `/etc/mongod.conf` to allow connections on the `10.10.xx.xx2` interface and restarted the `mongod` service? If so, have you checked that you have appropriate firewall rules in place to allow access between your servers on the expected ports? For more information on recommended security measures see: [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

Comment: I would also suggest testing with a `mongo` shell version that matches your `mongod` server to make sure the connectivity issue isn't related to the Node driver version (although that is a less likely possibility than `bindIp` and firewall configuration).

Comment: Hi @Stennie yes I have updated the `bindIp` settings and restarted `mongod` service. How ever I haven't checked the firewall settings. I will do how.

Comment: Hi @Stennie as per the mongodb documentation about `iptables` > Be aware that, by default, the default policy of iptables is to allow all connections and traffic unless explicitly disabled. 

So I assume that it would work out as is?

Comment: If the firewall is disabled or open, that shouldn't be a problem. What are you using as your `bindIP` setting? If you want to test the port is open you could comment out this setting temporarily to make sure it is not the issue. Have you also tried connecting from the `mongo` shell?

Comment: @Stennie I figured out that the problem is within the firewall rules. I just allowed the first server to connect to the other server where mongodb is residing.

Comment: Perhaps worth answering your own question to help others troubleshoot and fix a similar problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was within the firewall settings of the `server` holding the `mongodb`.

Using `ufw` I added a rule for the network to allow incoming connection from server 1.

`10.10.xx.xx1` = the app server

`10.10.xx.xx2` = the db server

With the said, Just do `sudo ufw allow 10.10.xx.xx1` on the db server.